# What is the passive voice of the sentence?

Tags: passive-voice

What is the passive voice of the sentence -" It is not here ."
 Possible answers :
        "It is there. " or,
        "It is somewhere else ."

Comment: Passives only concern action verbs. There is no passive voice of the verb to be on its own.

Comment: And for the most part passive is only possible with transitive verbs, or with intransitive verbs employed with preposition phrases designating an "affected" object.

Answer (score 2):

"Passive voice" describes what the verb is doing: A verb has passive voice when it acts on the subject; conversely a verb is active when the subject acts on it.

Since voice only applies to verbs that describe action, your question does not have an answer because "it is" is a construction of "to be" which describes state of being rather than action.

To rephrase your question the sentence needs an action verb like "It is not seen by her." In this example the verb "seen" is acting on the subject "It" so it is in the passive voice.

This example can be rewritten in active voice by making "her" the subject so she does the action on "it": "She does not see it."

Notice how the active voice does not use a construction of to be - is/was is generally an indication of passive voice but only when combined with action.